# Why am I getting an AttributeError message?

Tags: python, attributeerror

I have a file named tweets.txt. Each line is in the format:

> [latitude, longitude] value date time text

An example of the data contained in the file:

> [41.298669629999999, -81.915329330000006] 6 2011-08-28 19:02:36 Work needs to fly by ... I'm so excited to see Spy Kids 4 with then love of my life ... ARREIC
>   [33.702900329999999, -117.95095704000001] 6 2011-08-28 19:03:13 Today is going to be the greatest day of my life. Hired to take pictures at my best friend's gparents 50th anniversary. 60 old people. Woo.
>   [38.809954939999997, -77.125144050000003] 6 2011-08-28 19:07:05 I just put my life in like 5 suitcases

My assignment requires me to extract the first and second index of each line (latitude and longitude, which are integers). The problem is that these have characters such as "[","," and "]" and I want to remove these.

```
tweetfile=input("Enter name of tweet file: ")  
infile=open(tweetfile,"r",encoding="utf-8")  
for line in infile:  
    line=line.rstrip()  
    word=line.split()  
    word=word.rstrip(",")
```

As you can see, whenever I input an argument into the wordstrip line above, whether it be [, a comma, or [, I keep getting an error message saying:

> AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'rstrip'

Why am I getting this message? I thought I was doing the right thing. What would be the right way of doing this?

Comment: Because `split()` splits the line into a list of words, so`words`is a list. You would need to call `rstrip` on *each word in the list*, not on the list itself.

Answer (score 0):

`split` splits the string into a list. You are trying to perform `rstrip` on the actual list when you need to call it on each word.

You can loop through the list to achieve this:

```
for line in infile:  
    line=line.rstrip()  
    for word in line.split():
        word=word.rstrip(",")
```

Alternatively, you can split it like you already do & access the words you want via the index.

For clarification:

In your code, `split()` turns `word` into:

> ["[38.809954939999997,",
>
> "-77.125144050000003]",
>
> "6",
>
> "2011-08-28 19:07:05",
>
> "I",
>
> "just",
>
> "put",
>
> "my",
>
> "life",
>
> "in",
>
> "like",
>
> "5",
>
> "suitcases"]

You are trying to perform one `rstrip` on that, rather than the words themselves. Looping through the list accesses each word & allows you to use `rstrip`.

Comment: This wouldn't do anything apart from reassigning to the loop variable.

Comment: @MarcusLim They would still need to perform their actions required on `word`, but it should fix the error that they are currently having?

Comment: @AmandeepPasricha You need to perform it on each word. I've edited the answer to show an example of why it's needed.

Comment: @AmandeepPasricha It has an effect on the word during that iteration of the loop, but I didn't put any code in to use the word. I've only fixed the problem that you were having with not being able to call `rstrip`. Marcus Lim was saying that my code doesn't perform any other actions on it.

Answer (score 0):

The `split()` function returns a list that you cannot perform `string` functions on.
The problem is in using those 2 lines in sequence

```
word=line.split()  #this will actually return a list of words not just a word
word=word.rstrip(",")
```

In your case, if you're sure of this exact format, You can do this:

```
tweetfile=input("Enter name of tweet file: ")  
infile=open(tweetfile,"r",encoding="utf-8")  
for line in infile:  
    line=line.rstrip()  
    coordinates_string=line.split(']')
    coordinates_cleaned = coordinates_string[1:] #removes the [
    lat_lon_string = coordinates_cleaned.split(',') #split lat lon
    lat = lat_lon_string[0].strip()
    lon = lat_lon_string[1].strip()
    # convert to float if you would like then after
```

Comment: @AmandeepPasricha I edited my answer to clarify this, you used rstrip after split, rstrip requires a string, while split returns a list

Comment: The string part of the coordinates contained [ in the beginning and you want to remove it so you can use the numbers without causing corversion errors

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things wrong with your code.

First, in general, prefer using `with` to open files to `open`. You do not close your file object, so the OS thinks it's still open (in use) until you close Python.

Second, `split`, when run on a string, *splits* it into a `list` of strings. You want to strip commas from all such substrings, so you need to iterate through the resultant `list` - it doesn't make sense to run `strip` on the `list`, since it's not a string.

Lastly, iterating through the text read from the file in this way and reassigning to the `word` variable will not change that text inplace, but only what the `word` variable points to, so you won't actually see any effects.

Example:

```
>>> numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>> for i in numbers:
...     i += 1
...
>>> numbers
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

The reason is that `i` points to the integers from 1 to 5 in succession. When you execute `+=` on it, what you are doing is *changing what `i` points to*, rather than *taking the object that `i` points to and changing it*.

As an analogy: it is the difference between following a signpost to a house and mowing the lawn there, and moving the signpost to point to a different house.

Try this:

```
tweet_path = input("Enter name of tweet file: ")
with open(tweet_path, "r", encoding='utf-8') as f:
    coordinates = [line.split()[:2] for line in f]

cleaned_coordinates = [(lat[1:-1], lon) for lat, lon in coordinates]
```

*Really* lastly, as a note: the latitude and longitude are `float`, not `int`, and you can convert them accordingly if necessary.